# What is the angle measurement of this vector?

Tags: physics

A force of 240 Newtons acts at 30 degrees. Another force of 500 Newton acts at the same point at 240 degrees. Find the resultant vector and its magnitude and angle.
I got the magnitude using the pythagorean theorem. Now I don't know the degree.

Comment: Have you found the $x$-component and the $y$-component of the resultant?

Comment: @TobyMak is right. You need to find the x and y components of the resulting vector and then you need to take the arctangent of this ratio to get the angle.

Comment: The resulting vector will bisect angle between the forces. So...

Comment: @Vasya Bisect, really? How so?

Answer (score 0):

Find new vector:

$240cos(30)+500cos(240)=-42.1539$

$240sin(30)+500cos(240)=-313.0127$

Now use $tan$ to find the degree. $arctan\frac{-313.0127}{-42.1539}$$=82$

So the angle is $82$ so $180+82=262$ since it lies in the third quadrant

Comment: This seems to have an error or two.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is, the third quadrant means the angle measure is between 180 and 270. How do I know if I subtract 82 from 270 OR if I add it to 180?

Comment: Its because when you calculated $tanx$ to find the degree, you assumed $x$ was adjacent and $y$ was opposite leg of the triangle. So you have to use the $x$-axis not the $y$ axis as a reference